# Preferred User Interface for yes/no/preferred scenario in mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm not sure how to setup the User Interface for the following scenario:

> Are you available for 5:00 or 6:30, or
>   both?  And if both, do you prefer one over the
>   other?

So far, I've got two groups of radio buttons, but I'm stuck on the "do you prefer one over the other" scenario.  I'm thinking if they hold down the YES radio button, then it changes color or something to denote that they are not only available for that choice, but that they prefer that choice as well.

```
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <legend>5:00</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="Avail500" id="Avail500_0" value="0">
            <label for="Avail500_0">No</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Avail500" id="Avail500_1" value="1">
            <label for="Avail500_1">Yes</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <legend>6:30</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="Avail630" id="Avail630_0" value="0">
            <label for="Avail630_0">No</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Avail630" id="Avail630_1" value="1">
            <label for="Avail630_1">Yes</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Since mobile is a new mindset, I thought I should ask Stackoverflow instead of make up my own user interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/CMJ8K/ (Using Checkboxes)
- http://jsfiddle.net/CMJ8K/10/ (Dual options)

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="jqm-home" class="type-home"> 
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <div  data-role="fieldcontain"> 
             <fieldset data-role="controlgroup"> 
                <legend>Select Available Times:</legend> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="Avail500" id="Avail500" class="custom" /> 
                <label for="Avail500">5:00</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Avail630" id="Avail630" class="custom" /> 
                <label for="Avail630">6:30</label> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="Avail930" id="Avail930" class="custom" /> 
                <label for="Avail930">9:30</label>
            </fieldset> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Another plus is that is uses a lot less code

Comment: OK, I get the checkboxes, but 9:30 isn't an available time.  I'm stuck on the "do you prefer one over the other" scenario.  Like, how would I say "I'm available for both, but I prefer 6:30"?

Comment: Hmmm.  This allows them to check everything and it still doesn't denote which time they prefer over the other.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you shouldn't have radio buttons, you should use checkboxes, as radio buttons don't allow for multiple selections. Also, what you could do, is once the user clicks next, if the user has chosen both times, they are given clickable buttons to choose their preference.

Comment: I don't want them to choose both "No" and "Yes", so I think radio button groups are the way to go.

Comment: No, what I'm talking about is something more along the lines of you allow them to choose either 5:30, 6:00, or both. 5:30 and 6:00 would each have on check box. Upon submission, if both checkboxes are checked, the selection area would be replaced by a choice area where the user selects either 5:30 or 6:00 as their preferred time.